# Does javascript implement lexical scoping?

Tags: javascript, local-variables

Why does this return 2 instead of 1? Seems the second "var" is silently ignored.

```js
function foo()
{
  var local = 1;
  {
    var local = 2;
  }
  return local;
}
foo()
/*
2
*/
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 6):

In javascript there is only function level scope and global scope. you cannot create a block scope and it adds no special meaning and does not create any scope.

And this is how your code ends up

```
function foo()
{
  var local = 1;
  local = 2;
  return local;
}
foo();
```

In ES6 you can create block level scopes with the help of [Let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). ES6 is not supported yet. more on that [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#ECMAScript_Harmony_.286th_Edition.29)

Comment: it should be noted, that lexical scope is coming in the near future with ES6 let keyword.

Answer (score 3):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope) :

> JavaScript does not have block statement scope; rather, a variable
>   declared within a block is local to the function (or global scope)
>   that the block resides within.

The scope of a variable in JavaScript is the whole function in which it is declared (or the global scope), so you only have one variable `local` here.

Your code is equivalent to

```
function foo()
{
  var local;
  local = 1;
  {
    local = 2;
  }
  return local;
}
foo()
```

Note that ES6 (the new norm of JavaScript) does introduce a [lexical scoping with `let`](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations) but [it's not yet really available](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#let).

Comment: It's available for firefox and nodejs harmony.

Comment: @simonzack Didn't you notice I linked to the Kangax table ? Unless OP is coding server side he can't really afford being incompatible with IE and Chrome, that's why I said "not really available".

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't click your link.